# Trying to display the content of radio buttons in a form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a quiz using jQuery.
I have established the quiz questions and answers in a 2-dimensional array.
I have the answer choices (1-5) displayed in a separate array.
I have stored the answer choices to temporary variables and want to display them next to radio buttons.
The answer choices (noted in my code as answerA=answerChoices[j][0], etc) are being input correctly but they are not displaying. When I inspect the elements in Chrome, I see that they are being brought in. However they are not displaying next to the form element in #quizQuestion.

I am sure I am doing something silly but cannot identify it. CAN YOU HELP?

Here's the html:

```
<!--practice quiz-->
<div id="practiceQuestions">

<div class="questionBox">

  <div class="theQuestion">
  <span id="quizQuestion"><img src="images/Practice_Tips_Math.png"></span>
  <INPUT type="submit" value="Start quiz now" id="startQuiz" class="viewable">

    <!--answer key beginsb-->

    <div class="answerBox">
      <form name="answerForm">
        <input type="radio" value="a" id="answerA" name="quizAnswer"><br />
        <input type="radio" value="b" id="answerB" name="quizAnswer"><br />
        <input type="radio" value="c" id="answerC" name="quizAnswer"><br />
        <input type="radio" value="d" id="answerD" name="quizAnswer"><br />
        <input type="radio" value="e" id="answerE" name="quizAnswer"><br /> 
      </form></div>
      <!--answer key end-->

  </div>

 </div> 



</div>
<!--practice quiz ends-->
```

And here's the jQuery:

```
var questionAnswer=[
['How many moons does Earth have?',1],
['How many moons does Saturn have?',31],
 ['How many moons does Venus have?',0]
];

var answerChoices=[
[1,2,3,4,5],
[18,32,15,1,9],
[3,5,1,0,9]
]

function askQuestion(j){
    //create radio button answer choices a-e
    //var radioBtn =$('<input type="radio" name="rbtnCount" value="a"  id="q1a"/><label for="q1a">'+question[0,1]+'</label><br/>');
    //display questions
    //console.log(radioBtn);
var answerA=answerChoices[j][0];
var answerB=answerChoices[j][1];
var answerC=answerChoices[j][2];
var answerD=answerChoices[j][3];
var answerE=answerChoices[j][4];

    if($('#startQuiz').is(':visible')) {
        $('#startQuiz').toggle();
        }
    if($('.answerBox').is(':hidden')) {
        $('.answerBox').toggle();
        $('.answerBox').css('margin-top','20px');

        }
        // display the question
        $(".theQuestion").css('margin-top','75px');
        $("#quizQuestion").text(questionAnswer[j][0]);
        //display the answers
        $('form #answerA').text(answerA);
        $('form #answerB').text(answerB);
        $('form #answerC').text(answerC);
        $('form #answerD').text(answerD);
        $('form #answerE').text(answerE);

    };

$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#startQuiz').on('click',function(event){
        event.preventDefault();

        for (var i=0; i<=questionAnswer.length; i++)
            {
                askQuestion(i);
            }
        }); 

});
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you can put your code in a JSFiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't set `text()` to a radio button, so you have to have some kind of label next to the radio button:

update:

```
<input type="radio" value="a" id="answerA" name="quizAnswer">
```

to

```
<input type="radio" value="a" id="answerA" name="quizAnswer">
<label for="answerA"></label>
```

and update your jQuery:

```
$('form #answerA').text(answerA);
```

to:

```
$('form label[for="answerA"]').text(answerA);
```

**JSFiddle Example**

**http://jsfiddle.net/moogs/RWk3E/1/**